# C# - Random output from array to textbox

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm kinda new to array and I made a char array (with 174 things in it) but I don't know how to output it in a randomize way. I'm trying to make a secured code for my system. I wanted to output 13 char from that 174 char array into a textbox, but I don't think I get the logic. Thank you in advance! Here is the code that only outputs 1 char per button click:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int randomnum = rnd.Next(0, 174);
for (int x = 0; x <= 13; x++)
{
    textBox11.Text = chararray[randomnum];
}
```

Comment: Some lines of code will explain better your problem. Show what have you tried, what is the expected result and what you get instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is *almost* there, but there are a few issues:

1. You need to append the new character to the end of the string as apposed to just setting the `Text` value directly. You can do this easily with `+=` instead of `=`.
2. You need to pick a different random character for each iteration of the loop, so move your call to `.Next` inside the `for`.

Putting this together you'd have something like this:

```
Random rnd = new Random();

for (int x = 0; x <= 13; x++)
{
    int randomnum = rnd.Next(0, 174);
    textBox11.Text += chararray[randomnum];
}
```

Note however, that if this is for the purpose of security, using `Random` isn't great. You should probably use something like the [`RNGCryptoServiceProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider?view=netframework-4.7.2). For example:

```
using (var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
{
    byte[] password = new byte[10];
    rng.GetBytes(password);
    textBox11.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(password).Remove(13);
}
```

Comment: This allows for duplicate indices, not sure if that's a desired side effect or not.

Answer (score 1):

I've attached a screenshot of this code working. I had a small typo

This will change the seed for random

```
int seed = 1;
```

Create an instance of Random, we don't need to recreate it every time we need to use it

```
Random r = new Random(seed);
```

This only initializes the characters

```
char[] _myChars = new char[170];
for(var i = 0; i < _myChars.Length; i++)
{
    _myChars[i] = (char)(i%26 + 65);
}
```

This is the query you're looking for, it will query the characters and order them by a random order with `r.Next()`

```
var output = _myChars.OrderBy(o => r.Next()).Take(13).ToList();
```

This is only for displaying the output, you would want to use the output in your textbox

```
for(var i = 0; i < output.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(output[i]);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

[image: Working code]